# Why is nothing written in the Sqlite3 database with this PHP code?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I usually used PDO with `new PDO('sqlite:test.log');` to write in Sqlite3 databases with PHP.

Now, for a performance comparison, I'd like to try using the [`SQLite3` PHP class](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.sqlite3.php) :

```
$db = new SQLite3('test.db');
$db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log (a, b, d);");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->execute(array("a", date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"), 123));
```

Unfortunately, after this code is executed, nothing seems to be written: `SELECT * from log` gives no row.

What's wrong in my code?

I also tried `$db->commit();` or `$db->query('COMMIT;')` without success.

---

Context: I usually use PDO, but I noticed it takes ~ 50 ms for a simple 1) open of the DB, 2) add a row, 3) commit and close. So I was curious if it was any better with Sqlite3 class instead of PDO. Result: it's the same: ~ 50 ms.

Comment: Check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike PDO, you can't provide parameters in the arguments to `$stmt->execute()`, you have to call `$stmt->bindParam()` or `$stmt->bindValue()`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "a");
$stmt->bindValue(2, date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"));
$stmt->bindValue(3, 123);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you have an array of values, you can call `bindValue()` in a loop:

```
foreach (array("a", date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"), 123) AS $i => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue($i+1, $value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! How to `bindValue` 10 params in a single call instead of 10 calls of `bindValue`?

Comment: I added a loop to do it.

Comment: Nice, thanks @Barmar. Isn't there a built-in `bindArray` or something similar without requiring a manual looping?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3stmt.php) and you'll see that there isn't.

Comment: Why don't you just use PDO?

Comment: You can use a PDO wrapper that wraps around _most_ RDBMs - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php.

Comment: I usually use PDO @Barmar, but I noticed it takes 50ms for such a simple 1) open of the DB, 2) add a row, 3) commit and close. So I was curious if it was any better with Sqlite3 class instead of PDO. Result: it's the same: ~50 ms.

Comment: @Barmar Any idea how to speed up such a simple query? I'd like to do some logging on each PHP call of `index.php`, and I don't want this to slow down page generation for the client of another additional 50 ms...

Comment: If you're inserting lots of rows, use multiple `VALUES` lists in a single query, rather than multiple queries.

Comment: Maybe a flag to ask Sqlite3 to not commit immeditately, but in the next 30 seconds when it is idle? I don't want this logging to be a "blocking" IO operation. Note: I'm inserting a single row to the DB on each `index.php` visit.

Comment: I don't think the sqlite3 library runs asynchronously, so that's probably not possible.